# Use netsuite to list all products using PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl, netsuite

I am new to netsuite and am programming an online store for a client that uses it.  I'm having trouble finding any resources regarding how to connect to netsuite via PHP.  I've downloaded the PHPToolkit but can't seem to get it working and can't get any errors out of it to point me in a direction.  I'm open to using a rest or curl solution as well.  Does anyone have any experience with this or know where I can find good resources/sample code?

Comment: I'm using netsuite version 2013.2

Comment: There is sample code in the Toolkit folder.

Post some of your non-working code, and I'll troubleshoot for you.